# Resetting inventory status after order is cancelled

Tags: php, magento

I have developed the magento website and it works great. I'm getting all order emails and shipping going good.

Last week, a customer who visited our website placed an order and cancelled at the final step. That product's actual quantity is '1'.

After cancelling the order, the product inventory should be "In stock". But it's not changed. It viewed as "out of stock". I have marked
Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled "yes".

Comment: did you checked inventory under  `catalog > Manage Products` ? or are you using multiple store or store views ? also did you gave option to cancel the order from frontend, is this workd fine when you cancel the order from backend ?

Comment: Hi.. I din't give the option in the front end to cancel the order. The customer went back to page without making payment. Then the order is cancelled. I'm using store view only. I checked with inventory, nothing changed and product is still out of stock.

Comment: did you tried again as how customer did, still issue is there /

Comment: Yes yes.. I tried with the same. But the outstock is not turn into instock..

Comment: when customer went back to page, and he closed the site, at that moment what will be the order status ? ii guess usually it will be in `pending`

Comment: which payemnt method ? means you are telling he went to payment page  after click on `place order`and click on "back" button, is it so ?

Comment: Actually we are using Payumoney as a payment method. After placing the order, it goes to payumoney's page and we have to fill the details there. Without submit the payment details, the customer came back to website page. Then  the order is cancelled automatically.. I checked with some demo too

Comment: let me check in my site, we have payu money

Comment: okay. Thanks yaar..

Comment: for me its working fine only , are you using official extension ?

Comment: No, i dint use anything. After closing the payumoney page, my order status is cancelled. and the particular product's quantity become 1 but the stock is still "Out of stock". After the order is cancelled, in the front page my product shows out of stock. Pls help me to fix this...

Comment: means are you using payu extension gave by payu team or some other extenison ?

Comment: My client have payumoney account and they provide the key and we developers implemented in my website.

Comment: thats fine, but what about extenison , magento code , is your client gave and is you got from payu team ?

Comment: yes yes.. I just download from payumney.(Magento KIT) Everything is fine except this feature. I think we need to check the magento backend feature. Because, when the order is place, QTY decreases by 1(1 to 0) and stock availability becomes "Out f stock". After the order is cancelled by the user, QTY increases by 1(0 to 1) but stock availability becomes "Out of Stock" only..(remains same)

Comment: is it working for COD ?

Comment: No.. We dint enable that option. We can't do COD..

Comment: thats okay are you using any other payment method other than Payu ? or if you have any demo site or localhost , you can try enabling COD and check there. because once we cancel the order inventory will increase form `0 to 1`. if you check with COD, you will get to know  whether it is payu issue or COD issue ?

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks for your answer. Will check and let you know..

Comment: No.. We are using payu only

Comment: I have checked with localhost and it works. When the order is placed,it decreases the quantity and become out of stock. When I cancel the order from backend, the qty increases and become in stock. So, the problem is with payu. As you said, if they dint pay the order status should be pending right.

Comment: did you installed payu in localhost or you tried with COD ?

Comment: yes, if they didt pay , it should display `pending` state in backend ,for me same happening....

Comment: I will check with payumoney and just raised an query...

Comment: they may reply after one week , is that okay ?

Comment: if payu extension you are using gave by them, than try installing again in localhost , if you are using payu extension of google, than you need to contact them only.....

Comment: Hi, I just contacted payumoney. They told me that its a payumoney feature. There is a button called "back to", it will go to failure page and cancel the order. They asked to hide the button. If customer wants to caancel or don't ready to pay, they can close the window. Then the order status will be "Processing or pending". Then we people go back to backend and cancel the order.

Comment: are you okay with this ? i think they only can remove button `back to`

Comment: for me when customer click on "Back" button, order is cancelling and inventory also going back to `1` , if you want i will send you `payumoney extension`

Comment: Oh.. So nice.. Can you pls send me the extension? I will try in demo and work on it..

Comment: Hi, the inventory is going back to "1". It doesn't matter. Is the stock availability becomes "instock"??

Comment: yes, it will, let me confirm and tell you....

Comment: Okies.. Pls order something and go to payu. and click on "Back" button. And the inventory sure will go to 1. Check the stock availability.. It should from out of stock to "in stock"

Comment: let me check that....

Comment: you are right, for me also same issue is there, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168295/magento-auto-changing-the-stock-availability-from-out-of-stock-to-in-stock) may help you if you dont want to hide `back to` button....

Comment: I went through the above link yaar. But di'nt work on it. Will decide whether to hide the back button or some other solution.                                        So, if the customer ordered and dint pay, the order status is pending or processing. We need to go manually and cancel the order right?

Comment: if the customer ordered and did't pay, it will be in pending status, you can cancel that, once they paid the amount , it will display `processing` , i dont think you can cancel the order once it is in `processing` state.

Comment: Yeah Okies ji. The current solution is, we people need to hide the button and will work in other later.

Comment: sure, i posted an answer , please accept it. & you can let me know if you face any issues furhtur....

Comment: did you found solution for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243730/enable-cash-on-delivery-option-for-specific-productone-product

Comment: No no... I din't..

Comment: i posted a solution there, please accept this one and you can try that solution....

Comment: Ok ji.. Will do..

Comment: Hi.. I need to edit the invoice pdf template. app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php                                                I have to add "from" address to the template. I have done it for invoice e-mail template. Do you know how to change it?

Comment: you can edit it, but take local copy

Comment: copy file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php` & than edit it.....

Comment: Do you have any idea to add the from address? It should be hard coded..

Comment: sorry , i didt understood....

Comment: Yeah.. Do you have idea to change the code in Abstract.php? There will be 4 fields right. Sold to, Ship to,  Payment method, shipping method. I don't want the payment method. Instead of that, I have to add "from" address. (Client office address)

Comment: i think better to do that in phtml pages only, if you post new questionwith clear details  thats much better.....

Comment: if you solved payu issue please accept the answer and upvote it , also  check my ansswer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243730/enable-cash-on-delivery-option-for-specific-productone-product

Comment: Yes s.. sure.. I have tried one extension.. If I copy the extension key, its not installed. Getting error. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-pdf-invoice.html

Comment: do you use filezilla or ftp or cpanel ?

Comment: what error you are facing ?

Comment: HI.. Can you pls ans for my ques, How to enable Gift cards feature in magento like amazon?

Comment: Are  you there? Pls reply me

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/devsters-gift-cards.html

https://github.com/WarbyParker/Warby_BulkGiftAccount

https://github.com/merchantwarehouse/shopping-cart-integrations/tree/master/magento

Comment: you can check those extensions and whichever suits your needs you can use that one

Comment: please post question here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I have posted my query. I used the free extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/devsters-gift-cards.html. If I copy the extension and install using it, getting error message. I think it will support magento 2 version only... Pls check it out  and tell me...

Comment: no, it will support magento 1 also.....

Comment: did you checked questions and answesrs & review section there ? may be someone else might faced same problem....

Comment: hi, you should have informed before only na, wait i iwll teel you

Comment: paste the extension key here : http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php & download extension

Comment: Oh... ok .. let me try.. Thanks a lot

Comment: did you found solution ?

Comment: Hi.. I'm using this extension.   
magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/kartparadigm-giftcard.ht‌​ml                  Everything works good but the UI is not good to look. http://imgur.com/NNckrvq  I don't what I have to do now?..

Comment: either you have to other extension or other way to find solutioon or you need to fix UI using css, you can try some code and post the question here, so that lot of pepoles will help you.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Payu money extension, once we click on "Back" button, it will cancel the order and stock status will not change from "Out of stock" to "in stock", so you can hide the "back" button In payment page and if customer dont want to pay the money he will close the payment pages.

Comment: Hi guys, its not a perfect solution and it should be fix further

Comment: @LAKSHMI what issues you are facing ?

Comment: We cannot remove the "Back button" in payu page. It should be done with payumoney. We can't request them.

Comment: before you said like "they will remove it if we ask " na ?

Comment: No.. They won't. Eventhough they remove the back button, the problem never solve. Just I found it

Answer (score -1):

The product quantity gets back to its original value after the order gets the `canceled` status. Check the order status. It may be still listed as `pending payment`, even though the client abandoned it.